# Read USB to Serial port Info in Xojo

Tags: serial-port, usbserial, xojo

I am writing a simple code to find the USB to serial port in Windows platform, if the port is what I want (can be filt by VID/PID number), then the program will open the port.

I use MonkeyBread plugin, WinUSBDeviceMBS, with property of VendorID and ProductID, I can select specific USB port. sample code as following.

```
Dim devices() As WinUSBDeviceMBS = WinUSBDeviceMBS.devices
For Each d As WinUSBDeviceMBS in devices
    msgbox d.vendor+"-" + str(Hex(d.VendorID),"0000") + " " +d.product+"-" + str(Hex(d.ProductID),"0000")+d.serialnumber
Next
'this will give you a message box with "FTDI-0403 FT232R USB UART-6001 A60251HV"
```

Also, with help of Serial.serialport.Name, I can get the COM port name for serial device.
    dim i, count as Integer
    count = System.SerialPortCount

```
for i = 0 to count - 1
    Msgbox System.SerialPort( i ).Name
next 
'this will popup msgbox with "COM1" or "COM3"... all the valid port number, but no vendor info or product info
```

But I can't find a method to match those two together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only using Windows you will need to use the registry to get this information.

You can get a list of all COM ports on the system here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`. Values will be listed according to their type, so a real serial port will show up with a name \Device\Serialn and data COMxx, other devices might be different. If you look here you can find a name you can use to filter which type of device a COM port belongs to, then simply list these in your application.

You can do this in Xojo by using the `Declare` statement to hook into the API of the Windows DLLs:
https://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Declare

Here is a document on the Registry API functions, they will be used as described here, but using the `Declare` statement mentioned above:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145679

Comment: Yes, in the VB.NET I use similar method to read the winmgnt:\\.\... to read the PnpEntity. However, I don't know how to write a code in Xojo. As you mentioned to read registry, could you give a sample code? Thanks

Comment: Check updated comment, you'll need to use the Registry functions via the Declare statement.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, did you know does Mac OS X provide similar function to let programmer do the same job?

Comment: This depends. Since on OSX the device will show up as a tty device it's going to be different. I know that some vendor's converters will display as ttyUSB0 and others might show up as vendor specific, so it will depend on your device. There might be a way to trace through the system profiler to get at the VID/PID if you know them and check the tty device name from there - hope this helps.